# Different serializers for different instances in a queryset in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

In `generics.GenericAPIView`, overriding the `get_serializer_class()` method only dynamically chooses a serializer for the entire query set. Is there a way to apply different serializers to different objects in the same queryset based on some attribute value of the object? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it is entirely possible, not in the `get_serializer_class` thoough - elsewhere, and also not a good idea. Can you elaborate on what you are looking to achieve, since it is not a good practice to have different API response formats. Uniformity is useful.
Can you describe the use-case for two different serializers in more detail?

Comment: Yes. For example, I have 5 different types of notifications. Since I want to sort them by time, for efficiency reasons, I stored them in the same model and they are differented by the `ntype` attribute. The queryset is a list of different types of notifications sorted by time, and I want to apply different serializers to different types because there are extra attributes associated to each type that I want to return.

Comment: You could subscribe the get_seriakizer function in order to provide the right serialize depending on some field or method.

Comment: Why not use a single serializer method field that gets the right value based on the `ntype`? See the answer below on how to achieve this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 'dispatcher' serializer which will use type specific serializer. Please note that in this case type specific data will be presentted as `typeSpecificData` field.

```
class Type1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...


class Type2Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...


class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    typeSpecificData = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_typeSpecificData(self, instance):
        if instance.type == 'type1':
            serializer = Type1Serializer
        else:
            serializer = Type2Serializer


        return serializer(instance).data
```

And then you simply use `MySerializer` in your view.